How to improve Extensibility of adding sub-middleware in traefik custom middleware
I'm working on a custom middleware for traefik that serves as a base for other sub-middlewares.
Each sub-middleware implements an interface and has its own config structure. Here's an outline of my current setup:
// Sub-middleware interface
type INETMiddleware interface {
    ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) *sperrors.Error
}

// Configuration for the middleware
type INETConfig struct {
    *INETSession
    *INETGeoBlock
    *INETAntibot
    *INETHelloWorld
    InternalErrorHTMLFilePath string `json:"internalErrorHTMLFilePath" toml:"internalErrorHTMLFilePath" yaml:"internalErrorHTMLFilePath"`
}

// Example sub-middleware config
type INETHelloWorld struct {
    Message string `json:"message" toml:"message" yaml:"message"`
}

Each sub-middleware is initialized and executed in the main middleware like this:

    BaseMiddleware struct {
        next http.Handler
        name string

        mws                   []INETMiddleware
        internalErrorTemplate string
        logger                *zerolog.Logger
    }

func New(
    ctx context.Context,
    next http.Handler,
    cfg dynamic.INETConfig,
    name string,
) (*BaseMiddleware, error) {
    mws := []INETMiddleware{}
    // Adding sub-middleware
    if cfg.INETAntibot != nil {
        mw, err := antibot.New(ctx, next, *cfg.INETAntibot, name, cacheService, sessionService)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        mws = append(mws, mw)
    }
    // More sub-middleware can be added here...
    return &BaseMiddleware{next: next, mws: mws, ...}, nil
}


func (b *BaseMiddleware) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    for _, mw := range b.mws {
        err := mw.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        if err == nil {
            continue
        }

        if err.IsHandled() {
            return
        }

        b.logger.Err(err).Msgf("middleware: %s", err)
        b.handleInternalServeHTTP(w)
        return
    }
    b.next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
}


The problem is that i have to manually add each sub-middleware by checking the config and appending it to the list. This make it tedious to add new sub-middleware in the future.
Goal:

Make the process of adding sub-middleware more modular and less repetitive.
Each sub-middleware should have its own config structure and be easily added/removed without modifying the main middleware much.

Questions:

How can I refactor this setup to make it easier to add new sub-middleware?
Are there any patterns or best practices in Go or middleware design that could simplify this process?

Thanks for your help!
I try to implement chain of responsibility pattern middleware
but the current i see its does not differ much
and read some links
https://drstearns.github.io/tutorials/gomiddleware/
https://medium.com/@matryer/writing-middleware-in-golang-and-how-go-makes-it-so-much-fun-4375c1246e81
But dont know how to implment this will make its better
